# Query optimization in Postgres

Tags: postgresql

I have is over 25 million rows, I'm trying to learn what needs to be done to speed up the query time.

"Properties" column is integer[]. I created a GIN index on F."Properties", what is slowing my query and how do I solve it?

```sql
SELECT
    F. "Id",
    F. "Name",
    F. "Url",
    F. "CountryModel",   
    F. "IsVerify",
    count(*) AS Counter
FROM
    public. "Firms" F,
    LATERAL unnest(F."Properties") AS P
WHERE
    F. "CountryId" = 1   
    AND P = ANY (ARRAY[126,128]) 
    AND "Properties" && ARRAY[126,128]
    AND F. "Deleted" = FALSE
GROUP BY
    F. "Id"
ORDER BY
    F. "IsVerify" DESC,
    Counter DESC,    
    F. "PageRank" DESC OFFSET 0 ROWS FETCH FIRST 20 ROW ONLY


**Query Explain Analyze**

"Limit  (cost=793826.15..793826.20 rows=20 width=100) (actual time=12255.433..12257.874 rows=20 loops=1)"
"  ->  Sort  (cost=793826.15..794287.87 rows=184689 width=100) (actual time=12255.433..12257.872 rows=20 loops=1)"
"        Sort Key: f.""IsVerify"" DESC, (count(*)) DESC, f.""PageRank"" DESC"
"        Sort Method: top-N heapsort  Memory: 29kB"
"        ->  GroupAggregate  (cost=755368.13..788911.64 rows=184689 width=100) (actual time=12062.457..12224.136 rows=201352 loops=1)"
"              Group Key: f.""Id"""
"              ->  Nested Loop  (cost=755368.13..785217.86 rows=369378 width=92) (actual time=12062.450..12176.968 rows=205124 loops=1)"
"                    ->  Gather Merge  (cost=755368.12..776878.19 rows=184689 width=120) (actual time=12062.435..12090.924 rows=201352 loops=1)"
"                          Workers Planned: 2"
"                          Workers Launched: 2"
"                          ->  Sort  (cost=754368.09..754560.48 rows=76954 width=120) (actual time=12050.371..12060.077 rows=67117 loops=3)"
"                                Sort Key: f.""Id"""
"                                Sort Method: external merge  Disk: 9848kB"
"                                Worker 0:  Sort Method: external merge  Disk: 9840kB"
"                                Worker 1:  Sort Method: external merge  Disk: 9784kB"
"                                ->  Parallel Bitmap Heap Scan on ""Firms"" f  (cost=1731.34..743387.12 rows=76954 width=120) (actual time=44.825..12010.247 rows=67117 loops=3)"
"                                      Recheck Cond: (""Properties"" && '{126,128}'::integer[])"
"                                      Rows Removed by Index Recheck: 356198"
"                                      Filter: ((NOT ""Deleted"") AND (""CountryId"" = 1))"
"                                      Heap Blocks: exact=17368 lossy=47419"
"                                      ->  Bitmap Index Scan on ix_properties_gin  (cost=0.00..1685.17 rows=184689 width=0) (actual time=47.787..47.787 rows=201354 loops=1)"
"                                            Index Cond: (""Properties"" && '{126,128}'::integer[])"
"                    ->  Memoize  (cost=0.01..0.14 rows=2 width=0) (actual time=0.000..0.000 rows=1 loops=201352)"
"                          Cache Key: f.""Properties"""
"                          Hits: 179814  Misses: 21538  Evictions: 0  Overflows: 0  Memory Usage: 3076kB"
"                          ->  Function Scan on unnest p  (cost=0.00..0.13 rows=2 width=0) (actual time=0.001..0.001 rows=1 loops=21538)"
"                                Filter: (p = ANY ('{126,128}'::integer[]))"
"                                Rows Removed by Filter: 6"
"Planning Time: 2.143 ms"
"Execution Time: 12259.445 ms"
```

Comment: What the unnest()? What exactly are you trying to count there?

Comment: also provide the available indices on the table

Comment: To use the "any" method, i need to use unnest() or i don't know any other method.

Comment: @AristoX maybe show us what you have in Properties column as sample

Comment: Properties column is integer[]

Comment: Why are you unnesting to begin with? You are not really using the rows derived from that. If you want to count the number of elements in the array you could use `cardinality` and get rid of the unnest. But it's unclear to me what you are trying to achieve there.

Comment: What exactly are you attempting to count? Please provide table definition script (ddl), sample data as text - **no images** (even better a [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14)) and the expected results of that data, also as text.

Comment: F."Properties" are my categories and they are of type integer[] ,

I'm trying to list the most related queries in the first place, with F."CountryId"=1 in my query and containing at least 1 of the values ​​from F."Properties",

For example;{126,128} content that includes both comes at the top

Comment: `P = ANY (ARRAY[126,128])` and `"Properties" && ARRAY[126,128]` seem redundant - don't they do the same thing? To figure out what causes the duration, please run `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)` after setting `track_io_timing = on`. Does increasing `work_mem` give you a substantial speed boost?